# cf-runtime not working

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy a nodeJS native app to CF. I'm using cf-runtime module to figure out the real server's IP and port address my app is running on. However with adding the

```
var cf = require('cf-runtime');
var local_port = 3000;
......
....business code....

 }).listen(local_port);

  console.log('Proxy server running at localhost:' + local_port);
  console.log("host: " + app.host + " port: " + app.port);
```

I'm seeing an error as below:

> Creating Application: OK Uploading Application:   Checking for
>   available resources: OK   Processing resources: OK   Packing
>   application: OK   Uploading (44K): OK Push Status: OK Staging
>   Application 'leohu-proxy': OK Starting Application 'leohu-proxy':
>   .......Error: Application 'leohu-proxy's state is undetermined, not
>   enough information available.
>
> thu@geekdev:~$ vmc logs leohu-proxy
>   ====> /logs/staging.log <====
>
> # Logfile created on 2012-10-07 17:41:24 +0000 by logger.rb/25413 Skipping npm support: npm-shrinkwrap.json is not provided
>
> ====> /logs/stdout.log <====
>
> Proxy server running at localhost:3000 host: 172.30.49.236 port: 15669

Can anyone exlain why, or advise me what to do here?

A following question might be: can I access this app from another app by using the exposed host and port address?

Answer (score 1):

Base on your stage log, you are missing the npm-shrinkwrap.json file.

Here is 2 blog posts from Cloud Foundry. One is for Node.js Module support and the other is the new runtime module (which you are using).

- http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/24/cloud-foundry-supports-node-js-modules-with-npm/
- http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/08/21/new-runtime-module-for-node-js-applications/

I would recommend you to review the first url and apply what they have instructed. This should get your issue resolved.

Comment: i will try this out. thanks. am a bit confused though, what scenarios that needs this file? the demo nodejs project on CF website doesnot provide it.

Comment: There will be an update done on the docs.cloudfoundry.com about Node. Stay tuned :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert about CF. But I'll try.

I think your log is ok. But the app seems to be down by the health manager. (after starting app).

Is your app is just a proxy ? It maybe an issue here if I have right about the healt manager.

Hope it helps.

Lucas

Comment: right, its just a proxy. u are right about the health mgr brought it down though i have no idea why